# Detect Shift key is pressed without using events in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#

I need to be able to detect that the shift key is being held, but I don't want to use events or global variables to determine that. Is there an API in C# that lets you ask what keys are currently pressed instead of using the event?

Answer (score 20):

```
if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0)
```

This will also be `true` if another modifier key is also down (eg, Ctrl+Shift).  If you want to check whether Shift alone is pressed without any other modifiers, use

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
```

Note that even this will be `true` if another non-modifier is down (Eg, Shift+A).  If you want to check whether Shift and *only* Shift is pressed, you'll have to use an API call.

---

If you're in a class that inherits `Control` (such as a form), you can remove the `Control` qualifier.  (`static` properties don't need qualifiers in inherited classes)

Answer (score 8):

`Form.ModifierKeys`
(static property)

Comment: This works, but the property is inherited from Control not Form

Answer (score 2):

You can install a [low-level keyboard hook](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx).

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class InterceptKeys
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this available in C# but you can call [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(VS.85).aspx). This method returns the state of a key at the time the method is called.

To call it from C# you'll need to use interop like any other Win32 API.