# Determine whether modifier key was pressed

Tags: c#, key, modifier

I know how to obtain which modifier key was pressed in C# but I don't know how I can actually check if any modifier key was pressed. I need to check it in `KeyUp` event, is it possible any other way than doing something like `if(e.KeyCode != Keys.Control && e.KeyCode != Keys.Alt && ...)` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) != 0)
```

will help you detect whether a modifier key (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>) was pressed.
Check the Post below for reference:

[How to detect the currently pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/c-how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key/1100374#1100374)

Comment: Replace the "&&" operator with the correct "&" operator. ("Error: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' and 'System.Windows.Forms.Keys')

Answer (score 3):

To make sure no modifier key is pressed you can check if ModifierKey equals Keys.None.

```
if (ModifierKeys == Keys.None) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx) class has properties that you can check. For example, to see if the Alt key was pressed, you can write:

```
if (e.Alt)
{
    // Alt key was pressed
}
```