# Disable Ctrl or Alt key without registry using c#

Tags: c#, keycode, alt, ctrl

I got a question about `KeyCode` and disabling special keys. I know this question was asked a few times, but I didn't find an answer I can use and which works so I came here to ask :)

I'm writing a program which blocks every key or key combinations (like `Alt+F4` etc.). The application is not for me, it's for customers which only be able to navigate in this program. This all works fine, but I can't disable `Left CTRL, Right CTRL or Alt` key. I got this code for try blocking these keys:

```
private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LControlKey)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("LCtrl", "Warnung", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.RControlKey)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("RCtrl", "Warnung", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Alt)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Alt", "Warnung", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Delete", "Warnung", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
```

I only use `MessageBox.Show();` that I can see if it works. `Delete` key works fine, but the other one not. Is it possible to do this without editing the `registry` and for Win7? Does anyone know why or can give me a hint?

Cheers

EDIT: I block all other keys in this way:
[Blocking shortcut keys using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175675/blocking-shortcut-keys-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I already found this thread, but there is just a way for WinXP or editing the registry.

Comment: How do you stop the Delete key (or others)?

Comment: see the link in my edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not highly experienced in user input classes, but here's my input.

CTRL and ALT are examples of modifier keys. That is to say, they modify other (non-modifier) keys to create a key combination. Your UI is likely only able to pick up a complete key combination. For example:

```
private void keyPressed(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    e.KeyCode == Key.A; // True (pressed A)
    e.KeyCode == Key.Control; // False (no key pressed)
    e.Modifiers == Keys.Control; // True (user is pressing the modifier CTRL)
    e.KeyCode == Key.A && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control; (pressed key A with modifier CTRL)
}
```

As for disabling the key, you could just catch e.Modifiers:

```
private void ignoreCtrl(object sender, PreviewKeyDownArgs e)
{
    if (e.Modifiers != Keys.Control) { /* Pass to handler */ }
    else { /* Discard */ }
}
```

Again, I'm not experienced in your particular framework but this would be my guess. I used the following SO sources:

[How to use multiple modifier keys in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434867/how-to-use-multiple-modifier-keys-in-c-sharp)

[Determine whether modifier key was pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599391/determine-whether-modifier-key-was-pressed)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment because I have not tested it, but I need some code as example so I write here. You tell me if it works or not.

The [PreviewKeyDownEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.aspx) contains other properties that you can use to check if one or more modifier keys are pressed.
You can then try to set the [IsInputKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs.isinputkey.aspx) property to false to prevent further processing for whatever regular key has been pressed together the modifier key.

```
private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)

if (e.Control)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ctrl", "Warnung", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    e.IsInputKey = false;
}
else if (e.Alt)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Alt", "Warnung", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    e.IsInputKey = false;
}
```

Comment: `Alt` still not blocked in this way. But `Ctrl` is now blocked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the modifier keys? Such as below.

Note this is for WPF as you didnt state win forms or wpf.

```
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Control Button Down");
}
else if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Alt) == ModifierKeys.Alt)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Alt Down");
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at it :)