# How to check if a key was pressed in C#? (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, keyboard, .net-6.0

I would like to check if the `alt` key was pressed in c#. I could only find old information that didn't work. It would be helpful if you send an example with the `alt` key. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, specify UI: Win Forms, WPF, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to detect a modifier key outside of a `KeyEventHandler` method, you can use the static `Keyboard` class from `System.Windows.Input`.

Example from my WPF .NET 6.0 Application on Windows

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[KeyEventArgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599391/determine-whether-modifier-key-was-pressed)

There was a similar post that provides a solution for this. Look for the answer by Jim Mischel

You can use the KeyEventArgs Class

```
if (e.Alt)
{
    // Alt key was pressed
}
```

Comment: Not sure about earlier versions but this is not valid in .NET 6 and above