# Detecting Ctrl key being held down on application startup?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When our WPF application starts, it uses Single Sign On to log in.  To allow testers to simulate other users, we'd like to detect the Control button being held down on startup, and pop up a login dialog.

Comment: Stating your platform would be helpful. WinForms / WPF / Console / other ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I use in a WPF app to check if the control key is being held down in the constructor of the main Window. It uses [System.Windows.Input.Keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.aspx)

```
if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) > 0)
    PromptForMarketSelection();
```

EDIT - corrected bug pointed out by Coincoin

Comment: Might be better with (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) != 0

Comment: For .NET 3.5+
if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control))
  PromptForMarketSelection();

Answer (score 1):

A universal solution would be to p/invoke [`GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293.aspx), in case you can't find anything built into .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/winforms-accessing-mouse-and-keyboard-state) article it used ModifierKeys to find out what you are looking for

Comment: Link is down. Check http://web.archive.org/web/20141020154537/http://tech.pro/tutorial/760/winforms-accessing-mouse-and-keyboard-state for a mirror to the past.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link...scroll down to look at the answer by Jeff Wain.

[How to detect the currently pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/c-how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key)