# How to check if Shift is held during startup of a Tk / Tkinter program?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I want my Tkinter (Tk 8.6) program to behave differently when Shift is held when the program is starting up.

I know how to check the `state` attribute in mouse and keyboard events, but my detection needs to work even when the user doesn't cause any events.

I tried `<Configure>` and `<FocusIn>` events, but their `state` attribute is always `'??'`. I tried generating a virtual event, but its `state` attribute is always `0`.

Is there a way to query this information from Tk interpreter?

Comment: Can you get key status as the first thing program does while opening? If shift is held, it should detect as the first job, if not well... rest of the code works.

Comment: The thing is I don't know how to get key status other than from keyboard and mouse events.

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman I don't think so -- Tk reads key down and up *events*, and if the shift key is held down while the application is being launched, then the event is gone long before Tk has a chance to intercept it and read it. The only thing I can think of off-hand is to have the user *release* the shift key and listen for a keyup without a preceding keydown.

Comment: Whoa, of course!! I forgot about key up. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: It's not perfect solution, but it will do in my case. Thanks again for the idea!

Comment: @Aivar I'm sure there's some more-natural way to do it, but I doubt you'll find anything that's cross-platform compatible. You'll have to ask the OS what the keystate is, rather than listening for the event in Tk.

Comment: @AdamSmith I'm far better in C++ compared to python, but fun thing what I said works in C++. I thought it should be same in theory. I'll post an example code in C++ now, maybe it helps more. (with the output)

Comment: I'm ready to implement 3 different solutions to achieve Win+Linux+Mac compatibility

Comment: https://hastebin.com/cahimilela.cpp this is my solution in C++. It should work like this in python too, in theory.

Comment: There might be a problem with focus, in Windows at least.

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman that Windows.h include is what's pulling `GetKeyState` into scope, right? That looks like a binding to the OS layer, which of course can tell you what the current key state is. The problem is that doing this in Python through Tkinter you don't have a way to ask the OS what the key state is. Try to implement the same using a Tk event loop in C++ and you'll run into the same problem Aivar is having.

Comment: Got it now, I'll try to find a way for it in Python. Thanks for explaining! @AdamSmith

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman I think a "proper" solution will do much the same as your C++ code -- grab the key state through a call to the OS layer requesting it outside of Tk. That's just not the "natural" way to handle keypresses in Tkinter.

Comment: @AdamSmith it's been only 5 minutes but I'm already convinced that you can't do it inside Tk. Basically solutions are: check for key up instead in Tk or check the key down outisde of Tk and build Tk based on the result. That'll work!

Comment: @TuğberkKaanDuman I was testing the checking of the keyRelease for shift and checking if tkinter previously recorded a keyPress on shift by tracking the keyPress as a True/False result stored in a variable. The only problem I see with doing it this way is your program will have to rebuild itself after the fact because its very unlikely you will be able to release the button at the time where it checks for the down press.

Comment: NO DUPLICATE for me, hence the topic targets the question of detecting a held key BEFORE the startup, what is a fully different thing, then detecting the holding of a key as a gesture during runtime what is easily possible via events. The correct answer is therefore probably "technically this is not possible". Or any other news on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

[A window can only receive key events when it's focused:](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm)

> KeyPress and KeyRelease events are sent to the window which currently has the keyboard focus.

- `Widget.focus_set()` has proven to fail if you press the key before the window is created. This is a conscious effort to prevent [focus stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stealing). To override this, **use `Widget.focus_force()`** (delegates to [`focus -force`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/focus.htm)).
- Note that **the user needs to press Shift after the Enter or mouse click that they used to start the app** -- otherwise, it's considered a part of that input. In Windows, I confirmed with Spy++ that the app's window never receives keyboard events in such a case even though it gets focus. [.Net's logic to get key state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333167/detecting-ctrl-key-being-held-down-on-application-startup) [delegates to `GetKeyState`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Input/Win32KeyboardDevice.cs,94f93036613a656e) that also judges by window messages.

  - Windows offers [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx) that returns hardware key status. [Linux and MacOS lack such a feature altogether](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/168549-cross-platform-input/?tab=comments#comment-1998420) [because it's incompatible with the character device paradigm](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/1190).

Then:

- Use `<KeyPress-Shift_L>` and/or `<KeyPress-Shift_R>` to detect presses of the Shift keys ("`Shift`" doesn't work, it can only be a modifier).
- Set a flag to ignore repeating `KeyPress` events as per [GUI Button hold down - tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34522095/gui-button-hold-down-tkinter) of just [`unbind`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.unbind-method) the keypress handler.

---

A proof-of-concept app:

```
import Tkinter as tkinter

class HoldKeyDetect(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, keys, handler=None):
        """Detect holding `keys` in `widget`"""
        self.widget = widget
        self.handler = handler        
        self.binds = {}
        for key in keys:
            evid = '<KeyPress-%s>'%key
            self.binds[evid] = widget.bind(evid,self.keypress)

    def __del__(self):
        try: self.unbind()
        except tkinter.TclError: pass   #app has been destroyed
    def unbind(self):
        while True:
            try: evid,fid = self.binds.popitem()
            except KeyError: break
            self.widget.unbind(evid, fid)

    def keypress(self,e):
        try:
            if self.handler:
                self.handler(e)
        finally:
            self.unbind()        

class App(object):
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = root
        root.focus_force()
        self.h = HoldKeyDetect(root,("Shift_L","Shift_R"),self.set_mode)
        root.after(1000,   # larger than keypress repeat interval + code overhead
                        self.continue_)
        self.mode = False
    def go(self):
        self.root.mainloop()
    def set_mode(self,_):
        print "Shift mode set"
        self.mode = True
    def continue_(self):
        del self.h
        print "Mode=", self.mode
        self.root.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App(tkinter.Tk()).go()
```

Comment: I think maybe you should re-read the question? OP already mentions the problem with this approach, unless I'm misunderstanding your answer.

Comment: @AdamSmith better now?