# How to know when ctrl+space pushed?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I want to call function when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> pushed. I searched more but couldn't find what I want.

Comment: probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add an event handler for KeyDown like: `KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"` on your TextBox.
And then in the event handler:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Space && e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
{ 
      //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: thanks, how to prevent the space char to be input when this code runs?

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space && 
       (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {
        // Do what you need here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should get you working -

```
private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key == Key.Space && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
  { 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch all the keys, whether you have the focus or not, in your class you just need to add in the constructor:

```
// To capture keyboard
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(Window), Keyboard.KeyDownEvent, new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(keyDown), true);
```

And add the method: (it's an example, it's not for adapted for what you want)

```
private void keyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        code;
    }
    else if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)) &&    Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.T))
    {
        code;
    }
}
```