# Click a button then a random hotkey and print the hotkey as text on the button

Tags: c#, button, key, click, new-operator

I have a button and I want it so when you click the button the text will change to :
Enter your button or mouseclick now.
and when the button or mouseclick is pressed/clicked it will print the hotkey to the button.

https://i.ibb.co/fnDPf65/hotkey.png

I hope someone could help me with this i am very new to c#.

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        button17.Text = ((char)e.KeyCode).ToString();
    }

    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418199/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-shortcut-editor-textbox ?