# How can I determine in KeyDown that Shift + Tab was pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

How can I determine in KeyDown that <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> was pressed.

```
private void DateTimePicker_BirthDate_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
   {
       //do stuff
   }
}
```

can't work, because never both keys are pressed exactly in the same second. You always to at first the Shift and then the other one..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It can't work, because never both keys are pressed exactly in the same second.

You're right that your code doesn't work, but your reason is wrong. The problem is that the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key has a special meaning - it causes the focus to change. Your event handler is not called.

If you use a different key instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then your code will work fine.

---

If you *really* want to change the behaviour of <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> for one specific control, it can be done by overriding `ProcessCmdKey` but remember that many users use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to navigate around the form and changing the behaviour of this key may annoy those users.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (DateTimePicker_BirthDate.Focused && keyData == (Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("shift + tab pressed");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a key press combination (Tab, then Shift) like Ctrl K + D you will have to use this modified example which was taken from [MSDN social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/67d26d46-0a15-4199-88f6-1e08e295b578).

```
private StringBuilder _pressedKeys = new StringBuilder();

private void DateTimePicker_BirthDate_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        _pressedKeys.Append("Tab");
        return;
    }

    if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift)
    {
        _pressedKeys.Append("Shift");
        return;
    }

    if (_pressedKeys.ToString()."TabShift")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It works!");
         _pressedKeys.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
         _pressedKeys.Clear();
    }

    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}
```

Comment: `_pressedKeys.Add` there is no `Add` i use `Append`. And there is `."TabShift"` in `_pressedKeys.ToString()."TabShift"`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it in notepad and was missing the intellisense

Comment: thanks, there is another problem: what if user keep down the `shift` key and then press `Tab` ?

Answer (score 0):

First hook the Tab keypress event, then during the event, check the state of the Shift key.  Keep in mind that there are two shift keys; make sure you check both of them.

This very related post shows how to check the state of modifier keys:

[How to detect the currently pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key)

Edit: an insight provided by another answerer who justly deserves an upvote is that the default behavior of the tab key (to change control focus) must be suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer in
[this post](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/271241-how-capture-shift-tab-c-form)

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple.

You can do that using KeyUp Event in the TextBox

```
    private void txtBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {               
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Shift == false) // TAB Key Pressed
        {

        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Shift == true) // TAB + SHIFT Key Pressed
        {

        }
    }


    Or

    Using this you can identify Any Key is press inside the form

    //Add This code inside the Form_Load Event
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(KeyPressEvent);
    this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    //Create this Custom Event
    private void KeyPressEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Shift == false) // TAB Key Pressed
        {

        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Shift == true) // TAB + SHIFT Key Pressed
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple.

```
Using this you can identify Any Key is press inside the form

//Add This code inside the Form_Load Event
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(KeyPressEvent);
    this.KeyPreview = true;
}

//Create this Custom Event
private void KeyPressEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Shift == false) // TAB Key Pressed
    {

    }

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && e.Shift == true) // TAB + SHIFT Key Pressed
    {

    }
}
```