# how can i remove digit dash in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on phone number box. I have already made the format of `(888)888-8888`. But now I want to operate back space. If someone has given the wrong number so he can edit it.

The problem is that when I try to remove the last digits from right side. it stops removing the digits after 4 digits from end. It shows me the result like this `(888)888-`.

Here is my code for number and dashes format.

```
if (phonebox.Text.ToString().Length == 1)
                {

                    phonebox.Text = "(" + phonebox.Text.ToString();
                    phonebox.Select(phonebox.Text.Length, 0);

                }

                else if (phonebox.Text.ToString().Length == 4)
                {

                    phonebox.Text = phonebox.Text.ToString() + ")";
                    phonebox.Select(phonebox.Text.Length, 0);

                }

                else if (phonebox.Text.ToString().Length == 8)
                {

                    phonebox.Text = phonebox.Text.ToString() + "-";
                    phonebox.Select(phonebox.Text.Length, 0);

                }
```

here is the solution that I attempted but not sure whether it will work.

```
else if (phonebox.Text.ToString().Length == 9)
            {

                phonebox.Text = phonebox.Text.ToString()+"";
                phonebox.Select(phonebox.Text.Length, 0);

            }
```

Comment: dude I really want to help you but I seriously have no idea what you are asking

Comment: actually i want to remove that hyphen sign. which is after 6 digit in field. I can't figure out how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your approach to deleting characters but this line is not deleting the dash, it's just appending an empty string object.

```
 phonebox.Text = phonebox.Text.ToString()+"";
```

If you want to delete the last character, you can do this

```
phonebox.Text = phonebox.Text.Substring(0, phonebox.Text.Length - 1)
```

Or, you can just replace the `-` with an empty string.

```
phonebox.Text = phonebox.Text.Replace("-", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is going to be adding in a extra conditional in your if and if else checks. What I want you to do is add in

```
(Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Backspace) == 0
```

into your conditionals

This will check and see if the pressed key was a backspace or not. If it is then it wont execute the above mods to  your text field.

for example

```
 if ( (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Backspace) == 0  && phonebox.Text.ToString().Length == 1)
```

The SO Article referenced
[How to detect the currently pressed key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key)