# How to detect Ctrl+Click or Shift+Click on checkbox in Treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, treeview

I have a treeview with Checkboxes. For this example, consider we have root nodes only.
The user can select multiple checkboxes at once (matching a certain criteria which doesn't matter for this StackOverflow question) using a menu or toolbar.

However, I'd like to provide a shortcut for professional users:

If the user Ctrl-Clicks or Shift-Clicks one item in the tree view, other items matching the same criteria shall also be selected.

I have already tried the following events:

- AfterCheck
- BeforeCheck
- Click

None of the events has event arguments providing information about the mouse button or any modifier keys. Even

- MouseUp
- MouseDown
- NodeMouseClick

only provide information about the mouse button, but not modifier keys.

**How to identify modifier keys during mouse clicks on a treeview checkbox?**

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I could solve it with the link provided. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it. We could also mark it as duplicate. Whatever you like.

Comment: OK, I think it's best to just mark as dupe, so I've voted to do that.